# Multiple select in angularjs form

Tags: angularjs, forms, select

I have a simple form which is used to edit an existing object (event) via REST API. If the id is passed as parameter my controller calls the service to pre-fill the form.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div ng-controller="PersonListCtrl">
      <form novalidate class="simple-form" ng-controller="EventController">
        Title*: <input type="text" ng-model="event.title" /><br />
        Subtitle: <input type="text" ng-model="event.subtitle" /><br />
        Speakers:
        <select
            multiple ng-model="event.speakers"
            ng-multiple="true"
            ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in persons">
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" ng-if="event.id" ng-click="update(event)" value="Save" />
        <input type="submit" ng-if="!event.id" ng-click="create(event)" value="Create" />
      </form>

      <pre>event: {{event | json}}</pre>
      <pre>speakers: {{event.speakers | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
jugtaasApp.controller('EventController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $scope.event = {};

    $scope.update = function(event) {
        // TODO: update
    };

    $scope.create = function(event) {
        // TODO: create
    };

    if(!$routeParams.id) {
        return;
    }

    $http.get('services/events/' + $routeParams.id)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.event = angular.copy(data);
        $scope.event.speakers = [$scope.persons[0]];    
    });
});
```

The `PersonListCtrl` calls another service to retrieve the list of available speakers.

With this code services/events is correctly called and the fields (Title and Subtitle) are correctly filled, except the multiple select (speakers).

The multiple select contains all the available person, but if the event has some speaker they are not selected as options.

What should I do?

Comment: `$scope.persons` isn't defined in what is shown

Comment: $scoper.persons is set by PersonListCtrl, which calls the service to list available persons. The multiple select is correctly rendered, with all the persons, but nothing is pre-selected.

Comment: Need to use a service to share data across controllers or access the `$parent` since they are nested

Comment: Also using: `$scope.event.speakers = [$scope.$parent.persons[0]];` the result is the same

Comment: I mentioned the $parent, but using service is the best way

Comment: read the angular docs developer guide for answer to that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the use of select, since with the following directive (and no changes) it works:

```
<select multiple ng-multiple="true"
    ng-model="event.speakers"
    ng-options="person.name + ' ' + person.surname for person in persons"
></select>
```

I suppose the as was changing the object which is compared to determine the selection.

This link was very important to solve my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/maku/TXPJZ/